# 5 characters string ID like Northwind CustomerID

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, concatenation, northwind

I am looking to get a 5 character long string compiled from a string name, just like it is in [MS Northwind sample database](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23654) (Customers.CustomerID):

```
CustomerID  CompanyName
-----       ----------------------------------
ALFKI       Alfreds Futterkiste
ANATR       Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados
ANTON       Antonio Moreno Taquería
AROUT       Around the Horn
BERGS       Berglunds snabbköp
BLAUS       Blauer See Delikatessen
BLONP       Blondesddsl pere et fils
BOLID       Bólido Comidas preparadas
BONAP       Bon app'
BOTTM       Bottom-Dollar Markets
BSBEV       B's Beverages
...         ...
```

So the ID (code) is not totally random, it somehow resembles the content of the string name. Obviously, duplicity is forbidden, the code has to be unique. Let's assume:

```
DECLARE @StrCode NCHAR(5)
```

I'd start with thinging along theese lines - I would create a scalar function to check duplicities which would return 0 for no duplicities and 1 for found duplicities, the core check would be simply counting lines of the provided string code:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM MyTable WHERE StrCode = @StrCode
```

And then in an another function (input = StringName, output = @StrCode) I'd try few approaches, from the most readable to the least readable, and check each attempt for a duplicity along the way:

```
SELECT @StrCode =
   CASE 
      WHEN dbo.CheckForDuplicity(SUBSTRING(@StringName,1,6)) = 0     
         THEN SUBSTRING(@StringName,1,6)  -- get start of the string name
      WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',@StringName) > 0 AND dbo.CheckForDuplicity(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@StringName,1,3),SUBSTRING(@StringName,CHARINDEX(' ',@StringName)+1,2))) = 0
         THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@StringName,1,3),SUBSTRING(@StringName,CHARINDEX(' ',@StringName)+1,2))   -- get 3 chars from the 1st word and 2 chars from the 2nd
      WHEN dbo.CheckForDuplicity(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@StringName,1,3),SUBSTRING(@StringName,LEN(@StringName)-3,2))) = 0
         THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@StringName,1,3),SUBSTRING(@StringName,LEN(@StringName)-3,2))             -- get first 3 chars  and last 2 chars
      -- possibly other approaches...
   END
```

So the first one would get accepted. But there may be a lot better approaches I'm not aware of...

This is only a concept. Is this a good idea?

And what about using this StringCode as a primary key, as they do in Northwind? Wouldn't this string key slow down the things, in comparison to INT key?

Comment: I think in Northwind those keys are just hand-created

Comment: *Don't* use such keys, they are a horrible idea. In fact it's a cardinal rule that keys should *not* have business meaning.

Comment: Don't use Northwind as a guide either. Microsoft itself consideres it a very bad example and release the AdventureWorks samples over 10 years ago and the WorldWideImporters sample leter. Northwind was actually a very simplistic **Access** sample from the 90s, never meant to showcase proper relational design or even showcase SQL Server's features like schemas

Comment: just use auto-generated integer values (using an auto-increment field) for your IDs. I completely agree with the last 2 comments above, the approach in the Northwind examples are now considered to be very bad practice.

Comment: `Integer` is 4 bytes, `char(5)` is 5 bytes.  Not a big difference but it's worth mentioning.  The main problem you have with a key like this is how do you deal with keys for companies with similar names?  You have to code for all that, it's better to just use an `identity` and let SQL Server manage all that for you.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What benefit do you see from it?  Why is an IDENTITY column insufficient?  Why does it have to be human readable?  Describe the functional requirement, not the technical solution that you've set your self on...

Comment: This method will increase the fragmentation rate of your indexes. avoid!

Comment: Aside from everything everyone's already mentioned, imagine an automatic process coming up with a coincidentally rude, embarrassing or ambiguous abbreviation for a customer name and you'll see that there would be a need for manual input anyway. Given that that's the case, if you really wanted "stock tickers" like this (and as it has been pointed out, you probably don't, certainly not as physical keys), it should be up to humans to create them on first entry. At best you could use a query as a rough first draft, but then you don't really have to worry about getting it just right.

Comment: Well, it's interesting to read the comments, however it is a FACT, that the codes are widespread in certain industries and required by industrial users. As it stands now, I deal with ID-separated char(3) generated codes, which are not only meaningless, but often times missleading. Imagine a company called "Ice Cream Gods" - the only one of this kind in your customer base - and a code "ICE" given to totally different company...  In a mid-sized company, users get to use to the codes they see on dispatch notes around. They simply scream for codes like northwind shows...

Comment: and what happens when the company changes its name? IDs should be unique and persist forever. By all means generate an abbreviated code for the company as a convenience (although possibly users should do this manually, as Jeroen mentioned, to avoid certain problems), but what we're saying is: don't use it as the _primary key_ to uniquely and permanently identify that particular record in the database. Personally I'd just let the users do this. You can warn them if the code they enter is already being used for another client, to avoid ambiguity. Or just print the full customer name on the forms

Comment: Wouldn't they rather scream for enough room to print the full customer name instead, or rather be completely free of copying around symbolic codes because automated systems take care of shuffling the data around unambiguously? And if not, they probably should. Otherwise, it would suffice to show as much of the customer name as is reasonable, combined with the unique ID. `42358923 Alfreds F` might not look as snazzy as `ALFKI`, nor is it as memorable, but as a search key it would do.

Comment: @ADyson, yep, I get the idea and it is arranged this way (code is a separate field from ID). I only ask for opinions about primary key and I'm pleased to get even the "no" answer :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Nope, what they really scream for is a kind of short "nickname". Customers don't get to see the codes much, they're internal, accompanying the semi-products during the production. And yes, I did see some funny and possibly offensive codes (GAY for instance), but let the user select them and those kind of codes will be the first first to pick! That's for sure :-)